# What method will determine why systemd failed to load a "Wanted" target?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 system that uses `systemd` with a default target of `graphical.target`:

```
$ systemctl get-default
graphical.target
```

If I follow the chain of "Requires" and "Wants", I find that `graphical.target` ends up "Wanting" a unit file `widget.target`.

I notice that sometimes `widget.target` loads at startup, and sometimes it doesn't.  This is verified by the output of `$ systemctl list-units --type target`, which doesn't include `widget.target` on those instances where it fails to load.

The machine is currently in a state where `widget.target` failed to load on the last boot.  If I examine the logs for this unit since the last boot using `$ journalctl -u widget.target -b`, `journalctl` returns `-- No entries --`.  If I extend the search beyond the last boot, the only entries are routine ones that are not errors and don't refer to `widget.target` at all.

Does `systemd` provide any other method for explaining to me why it wouldn't load a "Wanted" target?

**More info**

`widget.target` wants only one other unit, another target, via a "WantedBy" in that target's unit file (which manifests as a file in `/etc/systemd/system/widget.target.wants/`).  The other target loads whether or not `widget.target` loads.

In addition, `widget.target` is itself wanted by four services.  Whether or not `widget.target` loads, one of these services loads and three do not, according to the output of `$ systemctl list-units --type service`.

That is, `widget.target` wants one target and is wanted by four services; nothing differs about the loading of any of these five units between cases where `widget.target` loads and when it doesn't.

Comment: What services, if any, are registered with `widget.target`?

Comment: No services are cited in the unit file.  I'm not sure what it means for a service to be registered, though, so let me know if you mean something different.

Comment: If a service is set to run at the `widget` target, it could be listed in `/etc/systemd/widget.target.wants`, `/lib/systemd/system/widget.target.wants` or `/run/systemd/widget.target.wants` instead of the `widget.target` file itself.

Comment: @ErikF I've added info about all units connected to `widget` in my post.

Comment: Is `widget.target` on a filesystem that is being mounted "simultaneously"? It looks like `widget.target` switches between available and unavailable based on timing. For the 2nd part, it's a problem with `widget.target`.

Comment: @waltinator I'm not sure what it means to be on a filesystem that's being mounted simultaneously.  What makes you say that the availability of `widget` is based on timing?  If there is a problem with `widget.target`, is `systemd` capable of reporting what that problem is?

Comment: Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script.

Comment: System startup runs startup tasks in parallel, and in any order, is why "timing". One task  is mounting disks, one at a time, controlled via `/etc/fstab`. Another is `systemd`. If, when `systemd` builds its tables, the filesystem containing `widget.target` has been mounted, `widget.target` is run. If not (timing), `systemd` doesn't see it.

Comment: It looks like your `widget` startup is misconfigured, not completing the service startup

Comment: @waltinator I'm not using `/etc/fstab`, everything being mounted is via `systemd`.  `widget.target` is on the local filesystem.  I'm certainly willing to believe that `widget` is misconfigured, but my question is if `systemd` gives me any tools to determine what the misconfiguration is